# Space between moving objects

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have some enemies in an array, they are moving left and right.
Simple code that updates enemies position:

```
// when the game starts, moveRight is true
var moveRight:Boolean = true;

for (var i:int = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
{
if(moveRight)
{
// they are moving right
enemies[i].vx = 2;
}
else
{
// they are moving left
enemies[i].vx = -2;
}

// limit movement
if (enemies[i].x >= 550)
{
moveRight = false;
}
else if (enemies[i].x <= 50)
{
moveRight = true;
}

// move enemies
enemies[i].x += enemies[i].vx;

}
```

Problem: Each time when enemies hit left boudary (x <= 50), space between 1 and 2 enemy is getting bigger. Im not good at explaining things in english, so I have uploaded pretty basic .swf example here:

http://www.fastswf.com/GXKix5s

Just watch what is happening with the enemy on the left side.

I can solve that problem by adding one line of the code (NEW CODE below)
inside if-else statement:

```
if (enemies[i].x >= 550)
{
moveRight = false;
}
else if (enemies[i].x <= 50)
{
moveRight = true;
// NEW CODE
enemies[i].x += 2;
}
```

It works even with multiple rows, you can see here

http://www.fastswf.com/icsom6A

So the question is what causes problem? 
Why the space between enemies is getting bigger each time they change their direction from left to right?
If I loop troguh the array backwards, I have problem on right side, not left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because when moveRight is set to true, due to enemies[0].x being less or equal to 50, enemies[0] has already had its velocity set to -2.

So on the loop that happens when moveRight is set to true, enemies[0] gets moved -2 pixels and then sets moveRight to true so that all the other enemies greater than zero get moved +2.

One way to fix it would be to move the check outside of the loop (only checking the first and last enemy):

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
{
    if(moveRight)
    {
        // they are moving right
        enemies[i].vx = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        // they are moving left
        enemies[i].vx = -2;
    }

    // move enemies
    enemies[i].x += enemies[i].vx;  
}

// limit movement
if (enemies[enemies.length-1].x >= 550)
{
    moveRight = false;
}
else if (enemies[0].x <= 50)
{
    moveRight = true;
}
```

Another could be to have two loops:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
{
    // limit movement
    if (enemies[i].x >= 550)
    {
        moveRight = false;
    }
    else if (enemies[i].x <= 50)
    {
        moveRight = true;
    }  
}

for (var i:int = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
{
    if(moveRight)
    {
        // they are moving right
        enemies[i].vx = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        // they are moving left
        enemies[i].vx = -2;
    }

    // move enemies
    enemies[i].x += enemies[i].vx;  
}
```

Comment: I added an example to the answer